# Need reason for why Vespa database stops suddenly?

Tags: vespa

I am using vespa as a database for some application. It was running perfectly okay and suddenly stops working. When checked with command `vespa-get-cluster-state` it returned the result as shown below: [image]

But when I checked with command `vespa-config-status` it return the result as shown below:
[image]

To rectify this type of issue, I have to again deploy the application using  `vespa-deploy prepare application.zip && vespa-deploy activate` and then restart all the services.

But I need to know the reason why the database stops suddenly. And how to handle this issue to make sure it won't happen again.

Answer (score 2):

By stopped working what do you mean? You mean the port 8080 of the stateless container has stopped listening? There are multiple services making up one running Vespa instance and the socket write error could indicate that the container is no longer listening for some reason.

vespa-logfmt inside the docker container could tell you why.

Comment: I have again encounter similar issue, this time I had the logs of the nodes.

Comment: Feel free to open an issue at https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/issues